# Will multiple non-ordered read queries within the same transaction return the same result?

Tags: mysql

I'm working on a piece of functionality which retrieves one or more instances of a particular entity. The entity in question has **multiple one-to-many relationships** with other entities. I need to populate the base entity with these relationships.

I first load the base entities, and then I run multiple subsequent queries which each loads a set of one-to-many relationships.

```
select [...] from hierarchynode_track this_ inner join hierarchynode hnd1_ on this_.hierarchynode_id=hnd1_.id inner join track trk2_ on this_.track_id=trk2_.id left outer join agreement_track agr3_ on trk2_.id=agr3_.track_id left outer join agreement agt4_ on agr3_.agreement_id=agt4_.id left outer join originalpublisher opu5_ on agt4_.originalpublisher_id=opu5_.id left outer join society soc6_ on opu5_.society_id=soc6_.id where hnd1_.id in (?) limit ?

select [...] from hierarchynode_track this_ inner join hierarchynode hnd1_ on this_.hierarchynode_id=hnd1_.id inner join track trk2_ on this_.track_id=trk2_.id left outer join genrenode_track grs3_ on trk2_.id=grs3_.track_id left outer join genrenode gnr4_ on grs3_.genrenode_id=gnr4_.id where hnd1_.id in (?) limit ?

select [...] from hierarchynode_track this_ inner join hierarchynode hnd1_ on this_.hierarchynode_id=hnd1_.id inner join track trk2_ on this_.track_id=trk2_.id left outer join hierarchynode_track thr1x3_ on trk2_.id=thr1x3_.track_id left outer join hierarchynode hnd1x4_ on thr1x3_.hierarchynode_id=hnd1x4_.id where hnd1_.id in (?) limit ?
```

The base query is always the same, but each query is eventually doing a join with a particular table. The query conditions will always be the same.

*Will these three queries always return the same set of base entities as long as i run the queries within the same transaction? No particular ordering is being enforced on the queries, and the queries are run with the transaction isolation level `READ COMMITED`.*

**Note** : An alternative would be to run a "base query" first and retrieve the entity id's from that result. From there, I could run each subsequent query with an `IN` to filter on the base entity. However, I suspect that an `IN` query may not perform as well when the number of base entity id's given in the `IN`  condition grows (e.g. 1000 - 2000 base entities).

Comment: @matigo post your comment as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer to this question is *usually*.

Query results that do not contain an `ORDER BY` are returned in the order they appear in the primary index used for the query. So, if the same criteria is being provided to filter on, then it is reasonable to expect the query engine to use the same index and return results in the same order. This means receiving sequential results if the index is clustered or contains an `ASC`/`DESC`, and FIFO results if the index is non-clustered without any implied sequence.